# after ubuntu installlation, space is missing on my harddisk

Tags: boot, partitioning

i started installing ubuntu and took out windows 10 completely during the installation..
but after the installation, when i checked my disk partitions 
927gb on linux filesystem
3 gb on linux swap
512 mb on efi

but my hard disk size is 1tb (1024gb so now rest 94 gb is missing 
can anyone help me out.
i tried if the windows 10 is still existing on the disk, but i didnt get any method 
and while booting the system i get a message on the top left corner 
/dev/sda2: clean,223062/60760064 files, 5079494/243030464 blocks ...
so does this mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation why space is missing. It is all about calculations (Apparent Vs. Actual). Drives are marketed in terms of decimal. So, 1 TB is in decimal, i.e. 1,000,000,000,000B while OS shows memory in terms of binary. Therefore, 1 TB is actually 931.32 GB (1,000,000,000,000/2<sup>30</sup>). I personally use a 1 TB HDD and a total space of 931 GB is justified. So, the space isn't missing but the awareness of the facts.

Comment: This is a good explanation - there should be a canonical answer somewhere...

Comment: @CharlesGreen There isn't a Canonical answer (if there's I am not aware of it). Actually this isn't specific to Ubuntu. By OS, **I mean every OS** including Unix, Windows and Unix like.

Comment: Ayuh - but it pops up often...

Comment: @CharlesGreen This game of Apparent Vs. Actual is going on from very long. There's even a 7% theory which says you get 7% less memory than the said memory which I believe is not legit since on one hand we are measuring in decimal and on the other hand in binary.

Comment: Forgot - sorry!